# Como trabalhar com tipo anônimo?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, linq

Tenho o seguinte trecho de código:

```
var filter = new { categoria = 1, cond2 = foo, ... };
p = new ProdutoBusiness().listarProdutos( filter ).ToList();
```

Queria trabalhar com esse tipo anônimo como um parâmetro para filtro, mas não sei como receber esse tipo de valor no método referente:

```
public IEnumerable<Produto> listarProdutos( tipo???? filter = null) {
```

Minha intenção é alterar a *query* de acordo com o que vier no filtro. Por exemplo:

```
if(filter != null){
   if(filter.categoria != ""){
     query = from P in con.produto
             join C in con.categoria on P.categoriaID equals C.categoriaID
             where P.ativo == true
             && P.categoriaID == filter.categoria
             orderby P.nome ascending
             select P;
   }
   [...]
 }
```

Alguma ideia/sugestão?

---

Se alguém tiver a mesma dúvida com esses tipos `dynamic`, mencionado na resposta, eu resolvi assim:

Popular o objeto:

```
var filter = new { categoria = 1, cond2 = foo, ... }
```

Recebendo o parâmetro:

```
public IEnumerable<Produto> listarProdutos( dynamic filter = null) {}
```

Obtendo o valor da 'chave':

```
var fCategoria = filter.GetType( ).GetProperty( "categoria" ).GetValue( filter, null );
```

Comment: Tipo anônimo é impossível. Dá pra usar `dynamic`, mas possivelmente, existem várias soluções melhores que isso. Qual é o problema de criar um tipo pra isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como o tipo exato do enumerável não é conhecido uma solução é indicar para o compilador que ele não deve verificar a tipagem e deixar para o tempo de execução resolver isto. Se faz com `dynamic`. Algo assim:

```
public IEnumerable<Produto> listarProdutos(dynamic filter = null) {
```

Mas se você sabe que será sempre esta estrutura e parece que sabe, então crie um tipo nominado normal e use-o no lugar do tipo anônimo. O tipo anônimo é uma facilidade quando sua estrutura não importa muito para o que precisa. Eventualmente pode até reaproveitar um tipo já existente. Talvez queira de fato:

```
public IEnumerable<Produto> listarProdutos(Filter filter = null) {
```

E teria:

```
public class Filter  {
    public int categoria = 1;
    public ALgumTipoAqui cond2 = foo,
    ...
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Typing/NoAnonymous.cs).

No C# 7 pode usar uma tupla que pode ser o mecanismo mais adequado para algum caso.

Mas dependendo da necessidade específica pode ter outra solução, talvez bem diferente do que está pensando atualmente.

Comment: ah entendi a ideia de criar a classe para o filtro, mas em que camada entraria? na model mesmo? como eu falei sou iniciante com C#, mas já agradeço pela ideia, já me deu uma clareada

Comment: @FabioMarcell não sei, não tem informação suficiente para eu dizer algo isto. Nem sei se daria para fazer isto em uma resposta. Tem que colocar onde faz mais sentido.

Comment: Ok, mas já ajudou com o problema inicial. Muito Obrigado =)